# Is it possible to make an API call to link a GA4 and UA property in a Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am migrating to GA4 from Universal Analytics and am planning to create a script to make API calls to create the new GA4 properties as we have many properties.

However, in order to prevent Google from creating a duplicate property come March.

1. I would either need to connect the new GA4 property to its UA counterparts
   or
2. Turn off the flag "Automatically set up a basic Google Analytics 4 property"

Is there a way to do either of these through an api? Or is the only option to do this manually through the Google Analytics UI?

I experimented with the apis available for property management and account management through the current api reference(v1beta) and was unable to find an api solution

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties